# ASP.net MVC 5: Redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a the session expire attribute

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var context = filterContext.HttpContext;
        if (context.Session != null)
        {
            if (context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];

                if ((sessionCookie == null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") < 0))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/Index");
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
```

and in my **controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(Login login)
    {
        //WebSecurity.Login
        User user = new User();
        string encodePassword = Crytography.EncodePasswordToBase64(login.Password);
        var consumer = user.Get(u => u.f_username == login.Username && u.f_password == encodePassword).SingleOrDefault();
        if (consumer != null)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.Username, false);
            var expiration = 3;
            var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, login.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(expiration), false, "Admin");
            var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            var authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
        }
        return View();
```

and my problem is when redirecting the navigation of the main page remained.

[image: Navigation Stays and the url is the same]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REzWu.png)

Comment: There are at least 2 problems here: 1) Session state has absolutely nothing to do with authentication and your ActionFilter is requiring session state which might not be initialized. 2) An ActionFilter is not the right place to do an authorization check, you should be using AuthorizeAttribute or a custom IAuthorizationFilter for that.

Comment: You need to mark your action with attribute where you define redirection logic.

Comment: Does your login page use a shared layout? Or is your login page a modal popup view?

Comment: @berniefitz yes i used shared layout, 

basically i have two master pages the main and the login

Comment: @Djayneeee So when your page redirects to the login page the main master page shared layout remains?

Comment: @Djayneeee Can you try using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirecttologinpage(v=vs.110).aspx to do what you need here?

Comment: @berniefitz yes sir, the navigation of the main page remains

Comment: @berniefitz i tried it before but the result is still the same

Comment: those data might be defined inside your layout page that is why its remaining in all pages.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV we used @RenderBody(); but i guess the problem is we have 2 master pages.

i uploaded a picture that'll will explain the situation; partially the login is redirected but the nav and the url is on the main page

Comment: @RenderBody() will render your page content inside your layout. So your layout style will remains same.I think Home channel and Logout tags are there in layout.